# How do I log data in Python in Columns and not just rows?

Tags: python, logging

I am running code in Python for my temperature logger project. Currently the output for each sensor is in captured in rows. I want to be able to have each sensor have its own column.

The current code is:

```
import os
import glob
import time
import datetime
import csv

#these tow lines mount the device:
os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')
 
class DS18B20:
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_dir = r'/sys/bus/w1/devices/28*'
        self.sensor_path = []        
        self.sensor_name = []
        self.temps = []
        self.rows = []

    def find_sensors(self):
        self.sensor_path = glob.glob(self.base_dir)
        self.sensor_name = [path.split('/')[-1] for path in self.sensor_path]

    def strip_string(self, temp_str):
        i = temp_str.index('t=')
        if i != -1:
            t = temp_str[i+2:]
            temp_c = float(t)/1000.0
        return temp_c, 

    def read_temp(self):
        tstamp = datetime.datetime.now()
        for sensor, path in zip(self.sensor_name, self.sensor_path):
            # open sensor file and read data
            with open(path + '/w1_slave','r') as f:
                valid, temp = f.readlines()
            # check validity of data
            if 'YES' in valid:
                self.rows.append((tstamp, sensor) + self.strip_string(temp))
                time.sleep(100)
            else:
                time.sleep(0.2)
    
    def print_temps(self):
        print('-'*90)
        for t, n, c, in self.rows:
            print(f'Sensor: {n}  C={c:,.3f}  DateTime: {t}')
            
    def log_csv(self):
        with open('log.csv','a+') as log:
            writer = csv.writer(log)
            writer.writerows(self.rows)

    def clear_rows(self):
        self.rows.clear()

s = DS18B20()
s.find_sensors()

while True:
    s.read_temp()
    s.print_temps()
    s.log_csv()
    s.clear_rows()
```

and results in output in row like so

[rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dntST.png)

how do I modify code so the output for each sensor is in its own column and looks like:

[columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sFsY.png)

Comment: What is the meaning of the second column (values are sensor ids)  in the output ?

Comment: Currently rows are appended to the file, this transparently take in account new  sensors (or the removing of existing ones). would it be easier to keep the curent data gathering mode and have a utility to get the report in the needed format for instance using  `pandas.pivot_table` .